Horizontal knots on 3 sphere
Motivation: First I  present  my  motivation for  this question  but this  motivational part is not my  main  question.
I  participated in  a  talk on  knot  theory. Then  I presented the  following  question:
Prequestion: In the  usual  consideration of  knots  we  project  a  knot  from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to  $\mathbb{R}^2$. So if  this  projection make  a homeomorphism between the  knot  and  its  projection then the knot is  an unkonted  curve.  What  about the  same  situation if  we replace  the standard  projection $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$  with the  Hopf  fibration  $q: S^3\to S^2$? Namely assume that we  have  a  knot  $K$ in $S^3$  for  which the  Hopf  projection $q$ gives a  homeomorphism  between $K$  and $q(K)$. Does  this  implies that $K$ is  unknoted?
I realized that perhaps the  question received  some  interest or  perhaps it is not trivial for participants.  But after the talk I  continue to think about this  question. I  did not have  any  idea but it  was a  motivation  for my  following  main  question:
My  main  Question:

Is there a  horizontal  knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$? By  horizontal  I mean horizontality with respect to the  standard structure of  $S^3$: Orthogonal connection associated  to the Hopf fibration?
If the  answer  is  negative is there another connection on $S^3$ associated to the hopf  fibration which  admit a  horizontal knot? Can  horizontal knots be  very  complicated: namely are there horizontal knots  with  sufficiently large unknoting  number?


The answer to your prequestion is no, such a curve must be unknotted.  If the Hopf fibration maps the curve homeomorphically to a circle in $S^2$, then either of the discs that circle bounds lifts to an embedded disc in $S^3$ (lifting property of fibrations), so your knot is bounded by a disc, i.e. trivial.  For your main question I'm not sure I know what connection you are referring to.

@RyanBudney  The  connection is the 2  dimensional distribution  orthogonal  to the  fibers

@RyanBudney I  am  aware of lifting  but why  embeded  lifting. Any  way  my main  question is  some thing else

A lift of an embedded disc has to be embedded.

@RyanBudney Yes  BTW  is  my  connection  explanation  clear now?

I don't understand what you mean by a connection assigned to the Hopf fibration.  Perhaps you are using this terminology differently than it would be used in a differential geometry text.

@RyanBudney I mean the stqndard defonition the vertical fibration by circle admit an orthogonal complement (a 2 dim. distribution orthogonql to fibration)

@RyanBudney I do not see what is unclear according to you

The plane field orthogonal to the Hopf fibration is a “standard contact structure” on the three-sphere. Knots whose tangent plane lies in this contact structure are called Legendrian knots.  These have a rich theory.

Thank you very much  for this  answer.

But the relation to horizontal  curves in 3  sphere?

Do you mean the  corresponding  concept in sphere

The standard contact structures $\xi_S$ on the three-sphere and $\xi_E$ on the three-space are related by (a) restricting to the southern hemisphere and (b) orthogonal projection. So the theory of Legendrian knots "is the same" in the three-space and the southern hemisphere of the three-space.

For a discussion of (a) and (b) (just above) see the first two pages of Contact structures induced by skew fibrations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by Michael Harrison - arxiv.org/abs/1904.00405.

I should point out that deleting a point from the three-sphere does take (via stereographic projection) the standard contact structure $\xi_S$ on $S^3$ to some tight contact structure $\xi$ on $\mathbb{R^3}$.  Then, by the classification of tight contact structures, there is a diffeomorphism taking $\xi$ to the standard structure $\xi_E$ on $\mathbb{R^3}$.  However this uses the classification, so is not very explicit.  It would be interesting to write $\xi$ down in coordinates and actually find the diffeomorphism.

In summary: the theories of Legendrian knots in the three-sphere, the open hemisphere, and the three-space are all "the same".
